# Spreading a value (or number of values) over a period of time (workdays) to aggregate a daily value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a simple resource allocation graph that allows me to spread the effort of a series of jobs over varying periods of time but am even struggling with understanding even how to start.

[image]

What I am trying to get to is something similar to the image - I have tried to use the excel Gantt as a starting point but I dont know how to start going about aggregating the values over the time period.
I am a relative newbie to the more complex features of excel so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the file you have or one with dummy data please? It'll be easier to solve if the exact layout of everything is known

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(AND(J$2>=$E6,J$2<=$F6),IF(J$4<>"S",$D6/NETWORKDAYS($E6,$F6),0),"")`

This will work for cell J6 and then you can drag to wherever else you need it.

The `AND` checks whether the current date is the day of or after the start date and also is the day of or before the end date. If true then it checks that it is not a weekend, if true then it divides the number of hours by the number of weekdays between the start date and end date, if false (the day is a weekend) then it returns a 0. If the `AND` statement is false then it returns nothing.

The only change to the sheet format I've done is to use the full date in row 2 (rather than just the date of the Monday that you have in your screenshot). This makes evaluating the current date easier. If you can't change your sheet to reflect this then please could you share a copy of your file as it'll be easier to provide a solution using the original file and I'll update my answer.

[image]

Comment: Works brilliantly - thank you very much!